# How to disable transparent select option in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am using material ui to display select option in reactjs application. But the options are transparent and difficult to see. Is there any way to remove transparency?
This is my code

```
<InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Client Code</InputLabel>
        <Select
          style = {{width : '100%'}}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={formik.values.clienCode}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>AB</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems there is some extracurricular CSS styling being applied. Have you examined the DOM to see what rules are applied against your UI to see what is setting them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing, though I'm using TextField with a select property to achieve the same thing.  I would agree that it seems something extraneous is causing this, but in my case its a new project with very little going on that could be affecting it.

I was able to fix it by setting SelectProps > MenuProps > MenuListProps, however I'm hoping there's a better way to do it.  But it may just help you in the short term.

First, I'm using makeStyles for inline styles and I have a style named classes.menu with the value:

```
menu: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background,
},
```

Then I added this attribute to my TextField component:

```
SelectProps={{MenuProps: {MenuListProps: {className: classes.menu}}}}
```

In your case, since you're using Select directly, it might be something like

```
MenuProps={{MenuListProps: {className: classes.menu}}}
```

Here's my entire component:

```
<TextField
    select
    id="searchType"
    name="searchType"
    label="Search type"
    color="primary"
    className={classes.textField}
    value={formik.values.searchType}
    onChange={formik.handleChange}
    error={formik.touched.searchType && Boolean(formik.errors.searchType)}
    helperText={formik.touched.searchType && formik.errors.searchType}
    SelectProps={{MenuProps: {MenuListProps: {className: classes.menu}}}}
>
    {Object.values(SEARCH_TYPES).map((searchType, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={searchType.type}>
            {searchType.descriptor}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your computed background color, it will likely be "unset" related to the MuiPaper.  I have an override on my theme to set to white.

```
export const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPaper: {
           root: {
               backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
           },
       },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this problem and it was caused by a typo in my theme:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    default: "#F9F9F9",
    paper: "FFF",
  }
})
```

I was missing the `#` in the color. This fixed it:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    default: "#F9F9F9",
    paper: "#FFF",
  }
})
```

Upon further reflection, `paper` is white by default so this was a no-op anyway. But I tested with a different color and this caused the same issue and had the same solution.